# HighCharts' Tooltip is not displaying after zoom in WebView of Windows Phone 8.1 App

Tags: jquery, html, css, highcharts, windows-phone-8.1

I have used HighCharts in a static html file to create a graph and set that html file to uri of webview of Windows phone 8.1.

The problem is that the tooltip on data points are not displaying after zooming.

I have tried a lot but met no success.

Below is html code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=500, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Highcharts Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
     <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #main {
            background-color: white;
        }
    </style>
   </head>
    <body>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="main"></div>
    </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">

  function loadGraph() {

            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'main',
                    zoomType: 'xy'
                    //resetZoomButton: {
                    //    theme: {
                    //        display: 'none'
                    //    }
                    //}
                },
                title: {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: x_axies_name
                    },
                    categories: x_value,
                    labels: {
                        rotation: -50
                    }
                },

                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: y_axies_name
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                series: [{
                    name: y_axies_name,
                    color: '#F16724',
                    data: y_value,
                    marker: {
                        enabled: true,
                        radius: 4
                    }
                }] //series
            }); //chart

        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any errors in JavaScript console? I am not sure if there is such thing in windows phone.

Comment: I am not getting any error. Everything works fine. Just there is problem of pinch and zoom on webview. Once i zoom the graph on webview, the tooltip on data points are not displaying.

Comment: It will be hard to debug :) Could you set [`click`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.click) event and compare  `e.xAxis[0].value` and `e.yAxis[0].value` with the value you click on? I guess there may be problem with Highcharts calculations. Here is [bug](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4924) reported on Highcharts bugtracker.